# Should primary key clustered index columns added to the non clustered indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Ok here is a non clustered index features

[image]

Now as you can see Id is the Identity column which is primary key and clustered. I can either include it into the index columns and mark index as unique or not include it to the index itself and add it as included columns.

Which one should be selected and why ? thank you

Comment: Why are you indexing every column? There is no need to add the key from the clustered index to the non-clustered index.

Comment: i am not indexing every column. actually i can create lesser column multiple indexes but i decided to compose multi column single index. those columns are being queried as where clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clustered key is automatically included in the nonclustered index, whether you include it explicitly or not. In other words - don't include it, unless you need to use a predicate that filters on the clustered key and then a couple of other columns (in that order) - in that case it may make sense to force it as the first column, as it'll otherwise be stored physically as the last column.

Comment: Which is yet another good reason why the clustering key column(s) should be **as small as possible** - they are stored in so many places....